# Find $b$ where $b^x=x$, $b>1$ has exactly one root $x$.

Tags: calculus

$b^x=x$, $b>1$ exactly one root $x$. 
So $(\sqrt{2})^2=2$ isn't correct since $x$ could also be $4$. ($(\sqrt{2})^4=4$)

Comment: The equation $b^x = x$ having a unique solution means that the curves $y = b^x$ and $y = x$ have exactly one point in common -- what calculus thing does that remind you of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the exponential curve $y=b^x$ with $b\gt1$ is increasing and concave up, it will intersect a line of increasing slope exactly once if and only if they intersect at a point of tangency.  For the line $y=x$, that requires

$$b^x=x\qquad\text{and}\qquad (\ln b)b^x=1$$

Going back and forth between these, we have

$$x=b^x=1/\ln b=b^{1/\ln b}=e^{\ln b/\ln b}=e$$

From this we have $\ln b=1/e$, so $b=e^{1/e}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=b^x-x$. Then $f'(x)=b^x\ln b-1$.

$f'(x)>0$ for $x\in\left(-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b},\infty\right)$.

$f'(x)<0$ for $x\in\left(-\infty,-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}\right)$.

$f$ attains its absolute minimum at $\displaystyle x=-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}$.
The minimum value of $f$ is $\displaystyle b^{-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}}+\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}$.

The equation has a unique solution if and only if $\displaystyle b^{-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}}+\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}=0$.

\begin{align*}
\ln\left[ b^{-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}}\right]&=\ln\left[-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}\right]\\
-\frac{\ln(\ln b)}{\ln b}\cdot\ln b&=\ln(-\ln(\ln b))-\ln (\ln b)\\
\ln(-\ln(\ln b))&=0\\
-\ln(\ln b)&=1\\
\ln b&=\frac{1}{e}\\
b&=e^{\frac{1}{e}}
\end{align*}

$b^x-x=0$ has a unique solution when $b=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$. $x=e$ is the solution as $\left(e^{\frac{1}{e}}\right)^e-e=0$.